c# WPF MVVM Datagrid Button Binding TextBlock to DataContext
I have a DataGrid within a UserControl.  The UserControl is connected to a ViewModel which holds the data for the DataGrid.  In this case, the data is for contacts.  I would like to make the "Name" column clickable with a button.
The problem is, I need to bind the TextBlock of the button to a property (ContactFullName) in the ViewModel, but it throws the error "Datagrid is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project" on the Text property of the TextBlock.  How do I fix?  Code is as follows :
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Width="Auto"
              ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyContactsList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              >
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="ContactName"
                                Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.BtnContactName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:TypeExtension DataGrid}}}"
                                >
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Image Source="..\..\Images\DG Cell Background.png"
                                               x:Name="ContactNameImg"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContactFullName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:TypeExtension Datagrid}}}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <!-- ... MORE COLUMNS ... -->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>


<TextBlock Text="{Binding ... RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:TypeExtension Datagrid}}}"/>, never seen TypeExtension keyword, isn't it a typo?

@ArthurEdgarov See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.typeextension?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
Explanation: If a class implementing MarkupExtension has the Extension postfix, then the XAML compiler will be able to recognize this class both by its full name and by its abbreviated name without the Extension postfix. In this case, x:TypeExtension is the fully qualified name of the x:Type extension.

@EldHasp, oh, as it said: "You live a hundred years - you study a hundred years". Thanks!

@ArthurEdgarov Where do you live? Russia?

XAML is case-sensitive in the names of types and their members.
See Case and white space in XAML.
In this case, you only need this binding:
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContactFullName,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>

